# How write the text "ї φ" at MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, latex, non-ascii-characters, tex

How write the text "ї φ" at MATLAB?

This code:

```
text(0.1, 0.1,'ї \varphi')
text(0.1, 0.3,{'ї $\varphi$'},'Interpreter','latex')
text(0.1, 0.5,{'\text{ї} $\varphi$'},'Interpreter','latex')
text(0.1, 0.7,{'$\text{ї} \varphi$'},'Interpreter','latex')
```

does not create the text "ї φ" at MATLAB 2012a and 2015b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ї is not supported by the latex interpreter. So make a double dotted i by putting double dots `\"` over an dotless i (`\i`):

```
text(0.1, 0.5,{'\"\i $\varphi$'},'Interpreter','latex')
```